# How to replace SSH key in local Git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have 2 laptops. On first one I've created a SSH key in GitBash (locally) and successfully added the key on Github, and established the connection.
Now I need to get this SSH key from Github and insert it locally on second laptop into GitBash. **How can I do it?**

Locally in folder ".ssh" I have 2 files:
[those 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgQgI.png)
But the coding up there does not seems to be similar to what I have on Github.

Comment: As [per your own comment later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826731/how-to-replace-ssh-key-in-local-git-bash#comment126928868_71827022), this is not an ssh *user* key problem at all, it's because you have told ssh not to trust the *GitHub host key* on first use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you usually do it. The normal workflow is to create a separate key for every machine/user and add it separately.

In github you only place the public key (usually there is some comment after identifying the key) - but for login you need the private part, which is not on github.

The folder you show a screenshot is the one containing the key. So in principle this is the one you would  need to copy.  But (at least on linux) ssh is very picky about the access right on its files (must be unreadable to anyone but the user) - in short it's a pain to get right, easier to just create a new key.

Another potential issue is git bash - many apps bundle their own variant, so it might well be that the actual key files are in some unexpected location.

and consider what @phd pointed out.

btw if ssh doesn't work github also works over https.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understood. From the first laptop I've uploaded a project on github (SSH used). Now I want download this project from github to my second laptop. I go to IDEA -> Git -> Manage Remotes and up there I should add the SSH URL from github. But the IDEA says it is not possible "the authenticity can't be established".
If I can't change the SSH key on my second laptop to equivalent one on github, how can I download the project?

Comment: @surleversant See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+authenticity+can%27t+be+established This is a problem with host key, not user key.

Comment: I think @phd might be right. Added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! It is not everything clear for me now in mechanics, but I could do it. As I understood: the first action on second laptop (when just start new project) always should be "clone" with HTTP link, after I've created a token, which helps me for future transfers. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

well, i do this on linux, but it works, i simply copy the two files in the new machine, then add it to the ssh-agent there, just like i did in the frist, as long both don't attempt to connect at the same time, no problem.

In case of any access right prblem, I just change it with chmod, but again, thats on linux...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).